# Deleting all unactivated accounts

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a question about deleting all unactivated accounts that has been registered over 24 hours. I am using MSSQL.

Database Setup:

```
account | usrActivated | regTime
test           0         1314223187
```

SQL Query:

```
$time = 24 * (60 * 60);
DROP FROM ACCOUNT_TBL_DETAIL WHERE usrActivated=0 AND regTime < $time
```

Would this work if I execute a query like this? Deleting unactivated account which are older than 24 hours.

Comment: Why not try out with a SELECT first?

Comment: Any particular reason why you are storing dates as unix timestamps instead of native Sql Server `DATE` types?

Comment: There is no reason, i just didn't know what else to do.

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from ACCOUNT_TBL_DETAIL
where usrActivated=0 AND regTime <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

assuming you're on MySQL.

drop is for removing tables from a database. delete is for removing records from a table.

Comment: Sorry about Drop i meant DELETE. I am using MSSQL as in SQL Server. I don't think Now() is a function in MSSQL.

Comment: @Silent - for SQL Server you could use `regTime <= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())`

Comment: @Null - Ah - I hadn't looked at the example data. I just read the "registered over 24 hours" bit.

Answer (score 1):

Not like you've expressed, since that won't delete anything at all.  Unless you have accounts created in 1970, anyway.  Try this:

```
DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_TBL_DETAIL
WHERE usrActivated = 0
  AND regTime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Don't forget to do a test run (replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *`) to make sure this does what you want.

Comment: Now() is not a function in MSSQL i am guessing.

Comment: Well, since you didn't specify MSSQL, how were we to know that?

Comment: Sorry about that so any other way?

Comment: Probably.  I'm not a frequent SQL Server user, so I'm not sure I can really help.  (I assumed MySQL as this seems to be the most frequently-used RDBMS with PHP, in my own experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound too skeptic, but I guess you might end up deleting someone registered a second before the actual execution of this SQL. He/She might be in the middle of Activating.

Comment: (usrActivated = 0) identifies anyone who hasn't registered, but the second part (checking for a day's interval) would end up deleting someone who registered just a while back (but hasn't activated yet).

Comment: That is the whole point to keep the database clean from filling up with spams. So who doesn't activate their account after registration their account will get deleted.

Comment: Let us say I register at 11:59 PM, browse through channels to watch something better. The delete script kicks in at 12:00 AM (1 min after I start to register). I finally decided to watch Late Night with Jimmy Fallon. I am back to complete the registration - attempt to activate. What would happen then?

Answer (score 0):

> Let us say I register at 11:59 PM, browse through channels to watch
>   something better. The delete script kicks in at 12:00 AM (1 min after
>   I start to register). I finally decided to watch Late Night with Jimmy
>   Fallon. I am back to complete the registration - attempt to activate.
>   What would happen then? – Arun Aug 24 '11 at 15:50

You could make it to where it deletes the inactivated individually. not just one day after they register but maybe 3 days? or however long you want to. But it isn't like the script would fire off every three days for the whole site. It would be just one person. Unless multiple users sign up at the same time then that would be the only time that script would fire off. Hope that answers your question.